# ExtJS Element to Component

Tags: extjs

I want to take an ExtJS element(div) retrieved from the DOM selector, and convert that to an ExtJS Component(a panel).  How can I go about doing this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the `contentEl` config. It places what is in the div into the panel.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ext-3.1.1/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <script src="ext-3.1.1/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
    <script src="ext-3.1.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script>
      Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = 'ext-3.1.1/resources/images/default/s.gif';
      Ext.onReady(function(){
        var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
          items: [{
            title: 'About Us',
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            contentEl: 'about_us'
          }]
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="about_us">We are a great team to work with!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: div content inside a panel]

Comment: Just to be clear, this is simply using the element's innerHTML as a new panel's body content -- NOT "converting" the element into a Panel component.  You actually can convert valid markup into a Panel component using the `applyToMarkup` method, which is different.  FYI.